# Wanton abuse of edit privileges detected

Tags: support, edits, fun, alleged-abuse

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18730/revisions) was edited to add in a comment to the post.  Clearly, the user has a high enough reputation that he/she should understand that this is *unacceptable* behavior, *but did it anyway*.  (shudder)

**What should be done?**

- rollback the changes?
- manually rollback the changes, informing the editor that he/she "is a jerk" in the commit summary?
- refer the editor to the FAQ?
- inform the SO team of this user's problematic behavior?

If this user *isn't* stopped, he/she could edit comments into *more* posts!

---

Oh, and:

[image: rejection]

Comment: Time to use a system banner to notify all about this

Comment: LOL.  Ban the [user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4/joel-spolsky)!!!

Comment: You're going to have a hard time - Joel is the CEO of Stack Exchange Inc (the company running Stack Overflow).

Comment: @GeorgeEdison That might explain the "LOL" at the beginning ;)

Comment: Are we taking action against edits made four years ago now?

Comment: YES!!!!!!!!!1one

Comment: Release the Kraken.

Comment: Ha, this is rich.

Comment: Did SO have comments at that time? Also the user might have had been a noob at the time he edited :P

Comment: Haha! This is pure gold.

Comment: @simchona "Release the Krachen" your comment gave me such a good laugh cheers

Answer (score 66, accepted):

We have taken corrective actions and banned the offending user, when he returns we will coach him and ensure he knows how to use the system correctly.

Thanks for alerting as to this problem.

<sub>Also, if anyone knows of any programming jobs out there please let me know. I may not have a job tomorrow.</sub>

<sub>Also, this probably was done prior to the implementation of the commenting system</sub>

Comment: Time to update my Careers profile!

Comment: What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account”?  -Joel

Comment: @BilltheLizard, I can't tell if you expect to be collateral damage in the purge or the replacement for waffles.

Comment: @PopularDemand I guess either one of those would be unreasonable, so my joke just isn't funny.

Comment: Actually, I thought part of the joke was that it worked either way. Take the credit, @BilltheLizard!

Answer (score 19):

Good catch! I actually recognize that user's name; I've seen him before, here on Meta. He posted [this "question"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100137/131713) just a few months ago that was actually only one of those "hey guys, just sharing some info" blog entries that doesn't actually *ask* anything. Looks like he didn't learn his lesson in his first three years of using the site. Jeff had to go in and fix that post personally ([revision four](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/100137/revisions))!

This Meta post is nice, but in light of this new information it's probably not enough. Yes, I did see waffles's answer, but it looks like [the ban isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4/joel-spolsky?tab=accounts) for some reason. I'm going to e-mail `team@stackoverflow.com` directly, hopefully they'll be able to take additional steps. I will update this answer with the e-mail chain when possible.

Comment: What's really scary is how much reputation this user accumulated before being caught, and he/she was even promoted to moderator on multiple SE sites!

Comment: Okay, I totally _meant_ to send that e-mail for real, but Real Life interfered and now it feels like it's too late to do it. So if anyone's wondering about that e-mail chain update, sorry, it's not happening.