# Remove "Being ignored by" message in chat profile

Tags: feature-request, chat, ignored-users

So it turns out when you're being ignored in SE chat, you get a nice red message in your profile:

> Being ignored by X users

At first I thought I saw it because I'm a mod in chat, but apparently it only shows on your own chat profile. It doesn't actually give the name of who's ignoring you either, just a number, so it's not even helpful as a "don't bother talking to this guy". Even as a mod there's really nothing I can do with this info as it's only shown for me; I can't even ban myself if lots of people think I'm a jerk :(.

There's nothing actionable about this information, and there's nothing helpful about it either. Even as a mod there's no "see who's ignoring you" option (Nor, IMO, should there be), so why is it even shown? It's not really friendly to remind me *every time* I see my chat profile that someone is ignoring me. And I can't really ignore **eyebleeding red text** in the middle of my profile either.

Since this is rather user-hostile and not helpful ([unlike other awesome chat mod tools we need](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132138/please-provide-moderators-with-better-tools-for-moderating-users-in-chat)), could we just remove it?

Comment: `and there's nothing helpful about it either` Well, there is something helpful there, most jerks don't know they are. ;P

Comment: @YannisRizos most jerks are quite aware of what they do, plus ignore stats aren't really a good measure of that anyway. I don't see anything productive in antagonizing users because someone ignored them

Comment: Haven't we had that discussion already, when you first found out? Of course it's useless.

Comment: Yes, but for some reason SE doesn't seem to implement every change I think of in chat, so I thought I'd make it a formal request.

Comment: I ignore people on their birthday. Would be pointless without this message.